# Simplify the strcat and sprintf with variable

Tags: c

I have been using the following code to concatenate any variable to a string followed by any file extension I want. This code helps me to coustomize the filenames I want to store in my machine:

```
char filename[50] = "Chunk#", val[50], ext[5]=".txt";
int x =1;
sprintf(val, "_%d", x);
strcat(filename, val);
strcat(filename, ext);
printf("%s \n", filename);
```

I am curious to find an alternative way to shorten the previous lines, i.e., lines(3,4,5) maybe all of them in one line!!!

Thank you.

Comment: You could use [`sprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) for the whole thing, couldn't you?

Comment: e.g. `sprintf(filename, "Chunk#_%d%s", x, ext)`

Comment: @cubrr or better, `snprintf()`.

Comment: @cubrr Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `sprintf` for the whole string, or better yet, `snprintf` as suggested by Sourav Ghosh:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
char filename[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Chunk#", ext[5] = ".txt";
int x = 1;
snprintf(filename, BUFFER_SIZE, "Chunk#_%d%s", x, ext);
printf("%s \n", filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a single call to `snprintf()`, and of course there's no need to initialize `filename` since it will all be overwritten:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50

char filename[BUFFER_SIZE];
const int x = 1;
const char *ext = ".txt";
snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "Chunk#_%d%s", x, ext);
printf("Built filename '%s'\n", filename);
```